# php how to create array key in order to sum the outcome

Tags: php, arrays

I have a result from `$totalitems` and I want to sum the outcome of that.
The result is always 0 most likely because the array key is [0]

When i do

```
foreach ($items2 as $totalitems){
    print_r ($totalitems[0]);
    $b=array($totalitems[0]);
    //print_r ($b);
    //print_r ($totalitems[0]);
    $items4[] = $totalitems;
}
```

then the result `647957685757577957577979797957796857796857684657687968574568575768`
and i want to sum all those numbers

Another thing i tried is to create an array from all the numbers but then when i try to array_sum it gives a 0

```
Array
(
    [0] => 6
)
Array
(
    [0] => 4
)
Array
(
    [0] => 7
)
Array
(
    [0] => 9
)
Array
(
    [0] => 5
)
```

Anybody a idea how to do this?

Comment: Maybe [`array_column()`](https://php.net/array_column) could help ?

Comment: could you add (a sample of) the source array `$items2` to the question please?

Comment: Does you want to sum each digits from digits string? It's not clear. Please provide the desired result

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev yes i want to sum all the digits

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the structure of the source array (`$items2`) is an array of arrays with numbers, following should work:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($items2 as $totalitems){
   $sum += $totalitems[0];
}
echo 'sum : ' . $sum;
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/unMot)

Comment: Please @MartinSchilder, accept the answer if it solve your question for futur readers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If `$items2` looks like :

```
$items2 = [[1],[2],[3]];
```

Computing the sum, using [`array_column()`](https://php.net/array_column) and [`array_sum()`](https://php.net/array_sum) could be :

```
$sum = array_sum(array_column($items2, 0));
var_dump($sum);
```

Result :

```
int(6)
```

An so on if most embeded :

```
$items2 = [[[1]],[[2]],[[3]]];
$sum = array_sum(array_column(array_column($items2, 0), 0));
var_dump($sum); // int(6)
```

Answer (score -1):

How about using `string_split` to split the digits into an array, loop through the array, and add every array value to a total sum variable?

Answer (score -1):

You can use next code:

```
<?php
$str="647957685757577957577979797957796857796857684657687968574568575768";
$result = array_sum(str_split($str));

echo $result;
```

- [str_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) - convert the string to chars array
- [array_sum](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum) - summarize all digits

[PHP code test](https://phpize.online/?phpses=f0496b55c8bcd681e328b0e7a6c89522&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)